# IIS 5.1 shows directory listing instead of running web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-5

I have a mvc web application, previously it was running, I don't know what I did, but suddenly web sites in IIS stopped working and I got some kind of hexadecimal error, the problem was port 80 was being used by some other application, I changed the IIS to use port 90 for web sites, but then my mvc application has stopped working with IIS, and IIS now shows directory listing of my mvc web application

what to do?

Comment: This question might be more for serverfault.com. But it really sounds like your IIS configuration has stopped executing scripts. It determines what to do with a directory by looking at a list of files to execute based on the "default pages" setting in the website configuration. Start there perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check the [following guide](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-vb) about deploying ASP.NET MVC applications on IIS. Also if you are using extensionless URLs make sure you have a wildcard mapping for the `aspnet_isapi.dll`.